# How to insert the subsection frame number in the frametitle?

Tags: beamer, numbering, titles

Let's say this is my presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{The beginning}
\frame{\frametitle{Begin}
    some text
}

\frame{\frametitle{Begin}
    some text
}

\frame{\frametitle{Begin}
    some text
}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the first slide's title to be *Begin (part 1)*, the second slide's title *Begin (part 2)* and the third one *Begin (part 3)*. I can simply type the extra *(part x)* with only 3 frames, but it gets quite a lot of work when one's working with a lot more frames.

How can I do this?

Comment: Will there be slides in between *part 1* and *part 2*?

Comment: @KevinC: Not for the moment, but I'd like the titles to be "renumbered" when I add frames between them in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no slides between *part x* and *part (x+1)*, then you can use the current page number minus the page where subsection starts plus 1. The following macro does the calculation:

```
\newcommand\subsectnum{%
  (part~\number\numexpr \insertpagenumber-\insertsubsectionstartpage+1\relax)%
}
```

## Full Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\newcommand\subsectnum{%
  (part~\number\numexpr \insertpagenumber-\insertsubsectionstartpage+1\relax)%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{The beginning}
\frame{\frametitle{Begin \subsectnum}
    some text
}

\frame{\frametitle{Begin \subsectnum}
    some text
}

\frame{\frametitle{Begin \subsectnum}
    some text
}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect and very elegant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you get the occasion, perhaps you should post an output of the updated code, so as not to confuse future visitors of this page.

Comment: @Jubobs: Done. Thanks for making the edits `:)` It takes an experienced TeXnician to notice that spurious space `;)`

Comment: @KevinC Thanks, but I'm more an "aspiring TeXnician". One day, maybe. No problem. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @HerrK. there is any way to do this if exists pages between the slides? There is not `insertsubsectionstartframe`.

Comment: @ArturoVolpe: If there are pages between slides, the case would be trickier, especially when the number of pages between `part`s are not the same. I believe it's still solvable though, by using a counter to track the pages between `part`s. You should post a question about this.